# Linear Equation in java

Tags: java, string

```
    String str="2x+5=15";
    //here how to find x
    String res[]=str.split([+=]);
    int x=Integer.parseInt(res[0].charAt(0));
    int y=Integer.parseInt(res[1]);
    int z=Integer.parseInt(res[2]);
    int res=(z-y)/x;
    System.out.println(res[0].charAt(1)+" is "+res);
```

Is there any other methods to solve those kind of linear equations?? i'm a beginner.. and this method looks so bad..

Comment: Yeah, it looks bad.  Try using a math package in Java for this sort of thing.  For example, it is possible to call R from Java.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're only developing this small program for fun, not for using it in a larger project. Your method work fine for this particular equation, but will fail for most inputs. What if there is minus sign in the equation? What if the factor before the `x` is written in more than one character? You could adapt your regex to detect the `x` and `-` sign to fix those issues. Also, what if `str` is not formatted properly? For example, there could be several "=" signs.This is a good opportunity to learn about Exception handling in Java.

Comment: oh! ok i'll try Tim

Comment: that is why i'm asking for help! francoisr

Comment: We can help you more if you explain the exact problem you want to solve. Are you trying to read and solve any single variable linear equation from its string representation? What assumptions are you making on the input? Can the factors only be integers, or also fractional numbers? In any case, you should make the `res` variable a `float` instead of an `int`

Comment: yes! exactly bro

Comment: There is a problem here `int x=Integer.parseInt(res[0].charAt(0));` !! what if in the equation you have `13x+8=19` for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like using a for loop to go through the `string` and checking for each `char` if its a special `char` like `(+, -, *)` and whenever you get to one take the string from the last time you hit such a `char` and parse it to an `int` and then just do the computation. You will need to be careful about a few things but you can always ask if you run into more problems.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching will help you :

```
String str = "-50000x -50000 = -150000"; //ax+b=c
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(-?\\d+)\\s?(x)\\s?\\+?\\s?(-?\\d+)\\s?=\\s?(-?\\d+)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
double a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;

if (m.find()) {
     a = Double.valueOf(m.group(1));
     b = Double.valueOf(m.group(3));
     c = Double.valueOf(m.group(4));

     double res = (c - b) / a;
     System.out.println(m.group(2) + " is " + res);   //x is 2.0
}
```

The pattern :

- `\s` is for space || `\d` is for digit
- number x +/- number = number
- You can have a `minus` or not
- You can have a space before or after each element (operator/number) or not
- it will also find the letter like 'x' or 'y' no matter,
- also better use `double` rather than `int` for the division

Explanation in detail is available with typing "java 8 pattern" in google // and on the website down there you have explanations for ALL element of the pattern I made

Example of perfect match here : [`Regex101 demo`](https://regex101.com/r/UjMgtN/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class stack
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    String str="2x+5=15";              //here how to find x
    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(str,"+=");
    String aa=st.nextToken();
    int x= Character.getNumericValue(aa.charAt(0)); //char to int conversion.
    int y=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    int z=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

    int res=(z-y)/x;
    System.out.println(res);
        }
    }
```

Here is the solution for your problem.